# AWS AppSync how can I tell if there are outstanding mutations when I'm offline?

Tags: graphql, offline, react-apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS AppSync, Apollo and React Native. One of the great advantages of using these together is that I get good offline behaviour. In my app, I can make changes while offline and they all get queued up and executed when I get back on line.

However, I'd like to be able to show the user if there are mutations which haven't been sent to the server yet. Just some little icon or something which goes away when everything is up-to-date.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've looked at the offline configuration for `AWSAppSyncClient`, and can see there's a `callback` I can hook into, but it doesn't give me enough information as far as I can tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using the amplify library - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?

When you make a mutation while the device is offline - it gets added to a local queue (persisted by sqlite). It is from this queue that they are read and sent to server serially once back online.

Now while offline - your appcode would be able to query the local datastore to determine the mutations still 'offline'

Read more here:

- https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api#client-architecture
- https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/api#offline-mutations